# MySQL. Select a value and use in calculating another value in one statement?

Tags: mysql, select

Is it possible to select a value and use it processing another value in one select statement?

Something like:

```
SELECT a, b, (value a * 2) as c from table?
```

Update.

```
Select concat(a*2+a*4+10) as aa, b, (value (aa) * 2) as c from table?
```

Is it still possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that, standard sql stuff. Just repeat the name of the field (`a`) again in the expression.

Comment: Just do SELECT a, b, (a * 2) as c from table...

Comment: Remove `value`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please, see update. Is it still possible?

Comment: The updated question is a duplicate, see duplicate link above.

Comment: Any other solution than:
- subquery (well, fine, but kinda complicated for using in big reports);
- creating view(s) - still, rather complex, though makes the final query easier to read;
- using variables (does not work - sql manual);
?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. In your example column "a" then must be a type int.

```
SELECT a, b, (a * 2) as c from table
```